# How to edit a script that is inside one of your entries in the $PATH variable in one command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I would like to stream line the amount my command line workflow.
One way of me to do this is to write less characters.

So when I want to edit a script that is in my $PATH variable, I normally type:

`which script-in-path-variable`

Then I would copy the output and paste it as an argument into vim like so:

`vim /pasted/path/to/script-in-path-variable`

I am just wondering if there are other ways of editing that file in less steps? Ideally not having to copy the output manually.

Comment: What about `vim "$(which script-in-path-variable)"`?

Comment: That would work! What are the quotation marks for? And what does the dollar sign do?

Comment: Consider whether directly editing anything in your path is a good idea.

Comment: Remember `which` may return a path to a binary file, and editing that with `vim` would not work well, to say the least.

Comment: I have my own script in a separate directory tree (not in PATH), and one of these script maintains a separate, flat directory (not in PATH) with symbolic links pointing to the individual script.  I can call them or edit them easily using tab-completion, something like `vim /myscripts/partial_path + TAB`.  I have the advantages of quick access and no need to modify PATH.

Comment: @Fred You are right, sometimes I install commands globally for a specific language. For instance PHP's package manager is composer. Composer allows you to install files globally by putting them in a directory and putting that directory in the PATH variable. So you are right I probably wouldn't want to use `vim $(which global-php-script)`. I may want to view that scripts contents, so using `cat $(which global-php-script)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bash you have the [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command itself. Command substitution occurs when a command is enclosed as follows:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```

This is very useful for cases like this, when you want to directly use the output of a command to perform another one.

So in this case you can use:

```
vim "$(which script-in-path-variable)"
```

The command substitution will be executed first and its result will be passed to the `vim` command.